# How do you get main camera move along a specific route?

Tags: unity

I've got a scene in the starting  of my project, and what I want to do is to get my main camera move along a specific direction and route.
Let's imagine I've got a 3-Dimensional array which contains The Positions of The points thereon. This is what I want to do :

1-Set the camera position on The first point and then go along with The other points, delay X milliseconds in each point and then go with the rest of it.

2-Whenever I will be able to change any of these parameters inside the script and programmatically:X,Y,Z components of The Position and Rotation of The Transform hierarchical property.

I'm sure enough trying to write an algorithm on my own would be a relatively difficult job, so please give me some tips and if possible a pseudo-code.
And finally I want this script to be launched at the beginning of the scene.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try searching for "camera spline" and you should find existing answers & tutorials describing this kind of feature.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, special thanks to @DMGregory :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkVR2Mf_U8Y

It explains about 2 scripts written in C# and in  my opinion is a good illustration. Ready and written scripts, fully have described my problem.
Also there is a download link for The script. I extremely suggest this video.

Comment: Welcome to gamedev.se! Unfortunately, this is currently a "link only answer." Although the resource pointed by the link answers the question, it is subject to link rot, which in turn could render your answer completely useless. To avoid that, please describe at least the core of the content of the external resource so that future visitors benefit from it. (It's ok to leave the reference in the answer, though :)

Comment: I'm afraid this still does not answer the question. What's in those scripts, how do they work, what would I need to do if I wanted to implement the feature in my own game?

Comment: I shall post a complete description on this issue, thanks for your guide dear @Alexandre Vaillancourt.